# How can I sync my home folder over network and internet?

Tags: server, sync

I use my laptop with Ubuntu-desktop to do all my work, but I also have a low-end desktop over at my office just sitting there. I've decided I'm going to install Ubuntu-server on it and use it to mirror my entire laptop home folder, to make things easier when I decide to format my laptop's hard-disk.

Whenever I'm at work, both machines are connected to a network and communicate easily (and high-speed) via ssh. When I'm not at work, the desktop is still accessible via ssh. Ideally, the syncing would take place automatically in the background, whenever I change something. It only needs to be one way: the changes I make on the laptop have to be synced over to the server, but the inverse is not necessary.

I know there's software for this out there, my question is: **What software can I use to achieve the above objectives and also take full advantage of local-network speeds when I'm at work?** Since I'll sometimes deal with large files, the syncing process needs to realise that the two computers are sharing a local network, and then take advantage of that (instead of always syncing through the internet).

Just to be clear, over-the-network syncing is actually more important to me here than over-the-internet syncing. I ideally the software would check if the former is available and, if not, try the latter; but if that's not possible, the first case is my priority.

Hope this isn't too long. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can only connect to your office server via SSH, then your best
choice is to use [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/): it can use SSH
as a transport protocol and uses a smart algorithm to speedup the
transfer of large files, by sending only the changed blocks.

Since you only need one-way synchronization, just set up passwordless
SSH authentication from your laptop to the office server, and then you
can start with a command as simple as:

```
rsync -e ssh -a $HOME/ myuser@officeserv:
```

adding `--include` and `--exclude` options to refine the list of
files/directory that you want to synchronize. For instance,
transferring program settings ("dot files") can be risky if the two
computers do not run the same OS (same version).  My suggestion is to
start by excluding all "dot files" (so, use
`--exclude="$HOME/.[a-z]*"`) and then selectively add the
configuration directories of programs that can safely be shared (this
has to be seen on a program by program basis).  In addition, web
browser cache and `$HOME/.cache` can always be excluded.  See the
"FILTER RULES" section in the `rsync` man page for a detailed
discussion of the include/exclude rules syntax.

However, `rsync` does not have a "continuous-operations" mode, so you
will have to run it periodically from your
[crontab](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/crontab/).

Comment: This sounds good. I'll test it as soon as I get the server installed. One question: does the SSH protocol automatically use the shortest connection to the server? I mean: will it connect through the local network if both the client and the server are in the office network, or will it always attempt internet connections?

Comment: By the way, you're correct about the browser cache. Any other suggestion of folders I should exclude? My objective is to sync all personal files, profiles, settings, and configuration files.

Comment: @Bruce Connor: SSH will connect to a remote host using the usual IP routing algorithm.  Updated answer text with suggestion for an initial exclude list.

Comment: Thanks. To avoid conflicts I might sync my laptop's home folder to a subfolder in the server (and not the server's actual home folder).

Comment: @riccardomurri by "passwordless SSH authentication" do you mean keyfile-based? or something else?

Comment: @d3vid yes, SSH agent- or keyfile-based authentication; but any authentication method that does not ask for a password interactively will do.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using rdiff-backup over rsync.  It's pretty much just rsync++.

unlike rsync which just a 1-1 mirror that transfers diffs, rsync has a history mechanism.  So if you screwed up and deleted something important, you can revert back to a week ago and get it back.

On the ubuntu "server" you just need to have ssh running to apt-get install rdiff-backup.

on the client.  I would either run this manually.. or via a crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash

  #backup.sh

  rdiff-backup -v5 --exclude path-to-annoyingfile  /home/user/ hostname::/media/data/snapshots/laptop 
  ## this will cleanup any backups older then 2weeks.  Adjust this as needed.
  rdiff-backup --remove-older-than  2W --force  hostname::/media/data/snapshots/laptop


  #!/bin/bash
  ##Restore.
  rdiff-backup -v5 --restore-as-of now --force user@hostname::/media/data/snapshots/laptop  /home/user
```

If you open up your port 22 to the internet.. you should be able to run the same script either ways.. just have it your hostname resolve locally to your local IP.

ie.   backupSrv.penguins.org   would resolve to the external IP of.  2.3.4.5
but inside your lan:  to 192.168.1.253

Comment: I think your script is missing a few line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no complete, pre-packaged solution to your problem that I know of. You probably have to write some small script yourself for that.

The syncing itself could be done by `rsync`, as already explained by Riccardo Murri. Rsync only transfers the changed parts of files, so it is perfect for this task.

You can use the [NetworkManagerDispatcher](http://linux.die.net/man/1/networkmanagerdispatcher) to execute scripts on connection/disconnection of a network interface. So you could write a script that checks if you are on the correct network and then calls rsync. This way your data would be automatically synced when you connect to your company network.

To periodically sync your data you can use cron, as already mentioned.

You should also consider security when using rsync via ssh. To synchronize without user intervention you'll need a passwordless keyfile. Anyone who has this keyfile can gain access to the server it belongs to. I would strongly recommend to encrypt your home folder to protect the data on the notebook and on the server.

Answer (score 1):

DropBox | [DropBox @ SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/65025/best-way-to-sync-two-computers/65029#65029)
http://www.dropbox.com/help/137

DropBox should be good in your case, works on Linux, mac, windows, easy setup and management.

[Download DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/)

https://superuser.com/questions/147315/dropbox-to-sync-nix-home-folders

http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncOtherFolders

Have a read through - it does support syncing via symlinks and if there are certain doc, graphics, spreadsheets you have to sync - you still can maintain a copy of them in dropbox or permanently save them in dropbox location to save the hassle.

Comment: I don't believe you can set your Dropbox to be your Home folder (at least not yet).

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/147315/dropbox-to-sync-nix-home-folders

http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncOtherFolders

Have a read through - it does support syncing via symlinks and if there are certain doc, graphics, spreadsheets you have to sync - you still can maintain a copy of them in dropbox or permanently save them in dropbox location to save the hassle.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using dropbox accross platforms. What I'm looking for here is something that lets me sync many GBs of files without fees, and taking advantage of local networks.

Answer (score 1):

Try Sparkleshare: http://sparkleshare.org/

There is a client in the Ubuntu repo and it has instructions on how to setup a server on their website.

Comment: looks like a great program - the least hacky solution; version 1.0 was released last month.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for 2015 should be Seafile: https://www.seafile.com/en/download/

Sparkleshare Developers say themselves their tool is good for many small and especially text files, but not so good for bigger and binary files..

And in terms of performance it outperforms both Sparkleshare and Owncloud.

Addtional it is far less ressource hungry then OwnCloud - so an instance can run on a Banana or Raspberry without any problems as an 24/7 running computer. (I would recommend an Banana Pi though, because of the Gigabit network and the SATA interface, it was a good choice for a file server at least for me.)

I sync my home folders with three computers. I exclude dotfiles, they are handled over a git repo and some logic around because - as Ricardo mentioned - there are some problems in sharing dotfiles and other configuration over different computers, even when its the same OS and release. Think about the monitors.xml for example, or some different layout for an IDE on you laptop and your multiscreen desktop - or a program opened on both computers.

Additonal to syncing, I backup this data - via borgbackup. Its a very nice new backup program, which does deduplicating, is very fast after the initial backup and and has a lot of features many tools are lacking.

Its the perfect setup for me.